# How to plot a complex equation in Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, data-fitting

I have an equation which is like this :

```
1/sqrt(x) = A*log(y*sqrt(x)) + B
```

I would like to use gnuplot to fit it to data I have from experiments, in a file 'niku.txt' which has my data of x and y points

In gnuplot I write it as:

```
set xrange [2000 : 900000]
g(x) = A*x + B
fit g(x) 'niku.txt' u 1:(log($1*sqrt($2))) via A, B
1/(g(x)*g(x)) w l ls 5 title "growth"

set logscale x 
set format x "10^%T"

plot  'niku.txt'  u 1:2 w p ls 3 title "Niku " , \
      1/(g(x)*g(x)) w l ls 5 title "karman"
```

but this is not working properly, could someone tell me what mistake am making here.

[image: plot I obtained, (x,y) plot]
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your current command, it is finding the values of A and B so that

```
A*x + B = log(x*sqrt(y))
```

You can use a function of two variables

```
f(x,y) = 1/sqrt(x) - A*log(y*sqrt(x)) - B
```

Then for a point on your curve, we should have f(x,y) = 0, so we can fit this

```
fit f(x,y) 'niku.txt' u 1:2:(0) via A,B
```

Now, if you actually need to plot this, we need to solve in terms of x,

```
y = exp((1/sqrt(x) - B)/A)/sqrt(x)
```

Thus, if we let `g(x) = exp((1/sqrt(x) - B)/A)/sqrt(x)`, we can do

```
plot 'niku.txt'  u 1:2 w p ls 3 title "Niku " , \
      g(x) w l ls 5 title "karman"
```

Alternatively, you can fit this g function as well.

Without your data, I can't test this, but I believe that it will give you what you want.

Comment: Is it possible for me to plot a function which is like this y = C1*log(x*y) + C2 ??

Comment: @Bow In general, no.  Gnuplot needs to have a function explicitly given, so you would have to solve the equation for y first.  You may be able to approximate it by plotting contours.  If we let `f(x,y) = C1*log(x*y)+C2 - y` then we are really interested in plotting `f(x,y)=0`.  So we can do `set view map; unset surface; set contour;`  in order to plot contours.  Then with `set cntrparam levels discrete 0` we tell gnuplot to only plot the points where f is 0.  Finally, we plot with `splot f(x,y)` - note this is a 3d plot.